# Can’t run Craft CMS :( Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft CMS:

Tags: php

Can’t run Craft CMS :(
Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft CMS:

The Mcrypt extension is required.
Please talk to your host/IT department about upgrading your server.

I am on Craft 2.6 and PHP 7.1. I have the mcrypt extension on my php.ini setting.

Comment: This error only occurs when trying to access the admin side of Craft 2

Comment: Please note I have verified I have the mcrypt extension setup and verified. Accessing the backend dashboard was working until I changed my cpanel password

Comment: If you go to “Select PHP version” section inside cPanel, do you see the mcrypt extension listed, and is it enabled?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably going to be something specific to your environment, so not really possible to give a real answer.

The most likely explanation is that your server doesn’t actually have the mcrypt extension installed. You could try to [verify that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230152), and install it if need be.

However, a better idea could be to update Craft to the latest 2.x version (2.9.2). [Craft has actually bundled an mcrypt shim since 2.7.0](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-2-7-released-with-php-7-2-compatibility), so it can run without that extension altogether. Fortunately, [the Craft 2 releases since 2.6](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master-v2/CHANGELOG-v2.md) don’t really have any big breaking changes, so updating shouldn’t be a major pain. And, with the latest Craft 2 release you should be able to bump PHP up to 7.4 if you want to (assuming all your plugins are updated and supports that version as well) - which could be a good idea from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue by going back to PHP 7.1.33. from 7.4
When I checked my PHP.ini on Cpanel, the PHP version was reading 7.1 and thought that the problem was other than the PHP version. However, when I checked the server: php -v, the version was 7.4
So, make sure you also check the server version if you encounter this problem. Only checking the php.ini may give you a misleading reading.
Now, I am able to access the admin dashboard.